# Msbuild step to generate c# file and then compile it

Tags: c#, code-generation, csproj, msbuild-task

I have a .csproj named P with a custom task in it.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="[FullTaskName]" AssemblyFile="$(TargetPath)" />

<Target Name="[CustomTaskName]" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <[CustomTask] />
</Target>
```

This custom task replace the content of an included file F in P. This replacement can lead to errors in F.

However when I build P (and then run the custom task), the build pass whatever the content of F.

How to include the new content of F when building P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `BeforeTargets="Build"` to `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"` seems to be working.